# iOS App Distribution

Tags: ios, distribution, mfi

We developed an iOS application for medical use. That app will be distributed by doctors with other devices MFI (made for iPhone) as a sealed package.

We have analyzed B2B distribution model but it requires an Apple ID for every single installation.

Is there any way to distribute that app without requiring an Apple ID? because it is intended to be used by eldest people who probably will not have one.

In order to make it easier for final users an option would be to deliver the iPod touch with the software pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an enterprise account, then you would be able to install it on multiple devices and deploy them with the app pre-installed.